# Does Android store the activities you've surfed?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app for a project. The thing is that I'm using BottomNavigationView to navigate through activites. However, there is an issue here, when I press the "Back Button", the app goes through every single page I've surfed even though I've been to a same tab multiple times.

What I want to reach is something similar to what Instagram has implemented: Going through a same tab just once despite having navigated through it previously.

Watch the gif to see what I mean. https://gyazo.com/a7f536dbe1b204923ea790db50e8a88e

I execute this code all the times I touch an item from BottomNavigationView.

```java
case R.id.bnHome:                                                               
     Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
     context.startActivity(intentHome);
     callingActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
     break;
```

The current situation: when I start to close: Search -> Profile -> Search -> Profile -> Home -> exit

What I'm expecting: when I start to close: Search -> Profile -> Home -> exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior could be reach with Fragments. Fragment it is like View but with own lifecycle similarly to Activity, they was created for reuse and decoupling UI. Here is [an example](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711) how to build exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use Fragment for more readable and maintainable navigation structure.

Secondly ,

Make your activity to single task

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
</activity>
```

Add finish() after your startActivity calls expect from Home.

```
case R.id.bnHome:                                                               
 Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(intentHome);
 callingActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
 finish();
 break;
```

It can be work but if you choose to use fragment you do not need to initialize bottom bar or common other views or actions for every page.